# Cannot change Date autoformatting to Number in Access VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Access Application that automatically generates an Excel report using data from a MySQL database.

The data entered in a specific column are incorrectly autoformated to date.

I had the same problem in another column where currency was autoformated to date and solved it by using .Format and not .NumberFormat, based on the solution proposed in a similar question posted here in stackoverflow.

More specifically, i used the following piece of code:

```
Range("G1", AmountLastCell).Select

    For Each c In Selection
        c = Format(c, "Currency")
    Next
```

Instead of AutoFormat.

Now that i want to convert the column to Number, using the same technique wont work( using c = Format(c,"Number"). All my entries in the column take the value "Num0ber"

The crazy part is that if i convert the column values to currency, i get correct results (meaning the absolute value is correct. save the decimals and the currency symbol).

Any ideas???

ps: NumberFormat("0") does not work. I also tried to convert the values to text using CStr and change the column to general but that did not do gthe trick either.

My declarations are the following:

```
Dim rst_Data  As ADODB.Recordset
```

This is where the data is stored

```
Dim report_Workbook  As Workbook
```

The workbook i create to save the recordset that i get from my DB.

```
 Dim c    As Range
```

The dummy variable i use when looping through my range to format each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

First, if you're iterating over a range of cells (even if you're writing this in access, I'm assuming you're manipulating the excel sheet as an object) when you get or set the value of a cell, don't you have to get or set it as `c.Value` or `c.Value = [assigned value]`?

Second, it might help to see your declarations.  In my experience they are the problem just as often as the code.

Having said that, if you're still stuck with the same error after replacing c with c.Value within the body of the loop, I do have a quick and dirty idea.

If the date value it misinterprets the number as is a cogent representation of the number (for example because it is a number field where each number is necessarily 8 digits [bank routing numbers for example] where the conversion is being made to 11/15/2014 from 11152014) you should be able to explicitly type convert using `CStr()` and use the split function on "/" then concatenate the elements of the array returned by the split methods to the string representation of the number you want then `CDbl()` or `CLng()` the resultant string back to the desired numerical data type. It's not a particular elegant solution to your problem, but it seems like it should be workable. This is what I do to wrestle the unwieldy oracle datetime datatype into usable form in access.

Try this:

```
Dim toSplit As String
Dim strArray As Variant
Dim outStr as String

For Each c in Selection

    toSplit = CStr(c.Value)
    strArray = Split(c, "/")
    outStr = strArray(0)&strArray(1)&strArray(2)
    c.Value = CLng(outStr)

Next
```

Comment: Unfortunately the date is not a cogent representation of the number. However, if i convert the date to currency, the currency representation IS a cogent representation of the number. How can i apply a similar trick to go from currency to number? Because trying to use Format did not work as i stated in another comment of mine. As for the c.value proposition, don't forget that i am just changing the format of a cell range, not the values of each cell. later i will post my declarations because currently i am not able to access the code

Comment: Okay, so you want to manipulate the range itself as an object using the properties available to the range datatype, then.  You're currently iterating through the cells in the selection (even though you're treating each cell like a 1xl dimensional range of cells) and trying to change their datatype, which the system treats like an aspect of their value.  When you `Dim c As Range` and then iterate through `Each c in Selection` each c is a range object, with a whole list of properties and methods.

Comment: Yeah but is there really a difference between range and cell? I mean, from the little i now a 1*1 range and a cell have the same functionality.

Comment: Leave the Dims and in the loop try
`toSplit = CStr(Format(c.Value, "Currency"))` / 
`strArray = Split(toSplit, "$.")` / 
`outStr = strArray(1)` / 
`c.Value = CLng(outStr)` / (each / is a new line, I don't know how to markdown these comments.)

Comment: If you explicitly type the value you're assigning to the cell (CLng(outStr)) the cell should inherit the new datatype (or so I am given to understand it.)

Comment: That last suggestion (in case you were wondering) is assigning the dollar value returned by formatting the value of the cell to currency and converting it to string, then assigning the resultant array created by splitting it on $ and . to strArray, then assigning the second element of strArray which should contain the three elements ("","_your_number_","00") (note, the first element in the array should be the empty string "" because the first character in the string to be split is a split character "$") and then converting outStr to Long Integer and assigning that Long Integer to c.Value.

Comment: For the record, i managed to get it done using a very DIRTY solution which i would recommend to no one...!

Answer (score 0):

I use `Format(c,"#")` to convert to number format or `Format(c,"#.##")` if you want the 2 decimal places.

Comment: What version of Excel are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks .... `c=Format(c,NUMBER)`

Comment: Sorry, I've been approaching this from an Excel point of view ... try c=FORMAT(c,"Standard") or c=FORMAT(c,"General Number") for Access 2010

Comment: This won't work either...I think i have exhausted all the usual tricks but i can't get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've been approaching this from an Excel point of view ... try `c=FORMAT(c,"Standard")` or `c=FORMAT(c,"General Number")` for Access 2010.

"Standard" gets you 2 decimal places and "General Number" gets you the number with no commas.

Comment: Only c=FORMAT(c,"Currency") works for some reason...All the other formats, including "General Number" which i was not aware of, don't work and the data remains date formatted...

Comment: Sorry rpd, I've given everything I got on the subject. I'm running Access 2007 and don't seem to have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the huge trouble you have taken! The issue is that i face the same problem i read other people are facing and feared of: The problem emerged abruptly and not from the beginning.

Comment: I use c only for the formatting. The actual column which is used as the selection automatically gets formatted to date although i have a NumberFormat statement earlier in my script.